# Abstract Classes inheriting abstract methods with differing parameter type

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Imagine I have an abstract class Animal with a method:

```
public abstract void fetch(Animal ani);
```

And then I have a class that extends this abstract class with the following:

```
public class GoldenRetriever extends Animal {
       public void fetch(GoldenRetriever pup) { 
             pup.paws = "I have paws"; 
       }
}
```

I want every class that extends Animal to have a fetch() method. However, the fetch method assigns some feature unique to the animal in question (dog's paws, cat's claws, etc.). For example, fetch() for cat would take the parameter fetch(FelineCat kitty) and say:

```
public void fetch(FelineCat kitty) { kitty.claws = "I have claws."; }
```

Thus, the fetch method takes in parameters that extend the abstract class Animal (and are thus animals). I've defined the method fetch() in Animal to take any parameter of type Animal. To me, this makes sense since cats and dogs are animals, but Java says that GoldenRetriever fails to override the abstract method fetch(Animal ani). Why is this?

Comment: What if you have `Animal` class with a signature like this `Animal<T extends Animal>`  and `Animal` class's `fetch` method accepts a parameter of type `T`. Then all your subclasses can have `fetch` method with their own type. So for example `public class FelineCat extends Animal<FelineCat>` class has method signature `void fetch(FelineCat kitty)` like this

Comment: isnt your fetch method just using the object itself? as in this or self, so no need for parameter handling, the method is internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem 100% correct, but I think I have some kind of a solution for your problem. The following code works, it might not be optimal since you always have to use the generic argument, but at least the typing is correct.

```
public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal> {

    public abstract void fetch(T ani);
}

public class GoldenRetriever extends Animal<GoldenRetriever> {

    @Override
    public void fetch(GoldenRetriever ani) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The big downside is that you can no longer, say, write a method like `public void someMethod(Animal x)` that can take any kind of `Animal` as a parameter.  Depending on the needs of the program, this loss of a key OO feature could be a show-stopper.  So this is not necessarily a solution.

Comment: That is just wrong, why should it not be possible to put such a method in the Animal class?

Comment: I'm not talking about methods that would go into the `Animal` class.  I'm talking about methods that would be written elsewhere that would work with an `Animal` parameter.

Comment: Yes that was an answer to the "my answer is wrong" which is obvisouly not the case. It answers the question how he could force an implementation of an abstract method to have the specialized class as argument. Answer to the opposit (how to have the not specialised class) is not necessary since this is the default behaviour of java. The questioner is still free to put methods expecting an Animal as argument anywhere (base and specialist class including abstract methods)

Comment: I have no idea whether we're talking about the same thing.  But I'm going to back off my earlier comment a bit; it looks like you can use `Animal` as a parameter and it will check at runtime to make sure classes match.  However, you have to be OK with using raw generic types, something which is usually discouraged.

Comment: Usually there is some extra class which handles the logic and its not the domain model itself. In that situation you dont have to put basically the same type as the current class as the generic argument. The purpose of this code is to ensure typesafety while maintaing the advantage of an abstract method.

Answer (score 1):

The method doesn't override because the parameter type is different.  You have to declare the method like this:

```
public class GoldenRetriever extends Animal {
    public void fetch(Animal pup) {
```

i.e. the parameter type still has to be `Animal`, even though you're writing a class that is extending `Animal`.

There's a good reason for this.  Suppose you have some other method

```
public void someMethod(Animal x)
```

You can pass any `Animal` as a parameter, including a `GoldenRetriever`:

```
GoldenRetriever gr = ...;
someMethod(gr);
```

Suppose that in `someMethod` you had this:

```
public void someMethod(Animal x) {
    FelineCat kitty;
    ...
    x.fetch(FelineCat);
```

Since `Animal`'s `fetch` method can accept any `Animal`, the compiler thinks that it must be OK to make this call, because a `FelineCat` is an `Animal`.  It has no way of knowing that `x` is actually a `GoldenRetriever`.  If it allowed the overriding method to take a `GoldenRetriever` parameter, there would be a problem, because the parameter is actually a `FelineCat`, not a `GoldenRetriever`.  So then when `fetch` is called polymorphically, and the parameter type is wrong, then what?

The compiler has no way to prevent this, because it has no way of knowing what `x`'s type is.  In theory, Java *could* have allowed the override to change parameter type, and made a check at runtime (probably throwing `ClassCastException` if it tried to get a `GoldenRetriever` to fetch some other kind of `Animal`).  I don't know why they didn't, but I'm sure there are good reasons not to do things this way.

But you can make your own runtime check:

```
public class GoldenRetriever extends Animal {
    public void fetch(Animal pup) { 
        if (pup instanceof GoldenRetriever) {
            GoldenRetriever puppy = (GoldenRetriever)pup;
            // now puppy is viewed as a GoldenRetriever, and any methods or
            // instance variables particular to GoldenRetrievers can be accessed
        } else {
           throw new WrongSpeciesException("..."); // or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The above answer assumes that the method signature is really what you want.  But following Mixone's comment, it may be that you're *not* trying to set up an operation that involves two animals, in which case you shouldn't have the parameter at all.  A method like

```
public void fetch(GoldenRetriever pup)
```

assumes that you have one `GoldenRetriever` that will be doing something with another `GoldenRetriever`, and that you just don't want a `GoldenRetriever` doing it with other kinds of animals.  In that case, I think the runtime check is the best approach.  But if you wanted an operation that only worked on one animal, you've written it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The method that overrides another method must have the exact same parameters, otherwises it's called overloading.
 Your `fetch` method must be declared like this:

```
public void fetch(Animal ani)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `Animal` class generic, like this one

```
abstract class Animal<TAnimal extends Animal<?>> {
    public abstract void fetch(TAnimal ani);
}

class GoldenRetriever extends Animal<GoldenRetriever> {

    String paws;

    @Override
    public void fetch(GoldenRetriever pup) { 
         pup.paws = "I have paws"; 
    }
}
```

This is called [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fetchanimal;

/**
 *
 * @author Amin
 */
public abstract class Animal <T>{


    public abstract void fetch(T animalType);
}
```

create now a new class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fetchanimal;

/**
 *
 * @author Amin
 */
public class FelineCat extends Animal<FelineCat> {
   public String claws ;
    @Override
    public void fetch(FelineCat animalType) {
     //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        animalType.claws = "hello";

    }

}
```

and now create the third class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fetchanimal;

/**
 *
 * @author Amin
 */
public class GoldenRetriever extends Animal<GoldenRetriever>{
    public String paws ;  


    @Override
    public void fetch(GoldenRetriever animalType) {
      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
       animalType.paws = "hello" ; 
        }


}
```

just copy paste the code